# Get elements innerHTML with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, innerhtml

I wrote this piece of code, but I'm not able to get the links:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const countries = ['us', 'gb', 'ca', 'au', 'de', 'nz', 'albania', 'nl', 'is'];

    const pia = 'https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/network/'
    await page.goto(pia);


    for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        let el = document.querySelectorAll(`#${countries[i]} > div > div > div.modal-body > div > .subregion > center > .hostname`);

        for (let j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
            let url = `htpp://${el[j].innerText}:8888/speedtest`;
            console.log(url);
        }
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

The thing is, when I paste "countries[...]" and the for-loop in the browser's console it works just fine, but when I tried it from Node it gives me this big error, even though it prints the whole page if I use the "await page.content()" function:

```
(node:16300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at C:\Users\jason\Desktop\pptr\script.js:15:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:16300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16300) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I thought it could be the way I'm targeting the elements, but again it works fine in the browser's console. What am I missing? All the help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: `document` doesn't exist in the context of Node.JS. You need to use the `evaluate` function if you want to execute code on the browser.

Comment: thanks! I'm still learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Puppeteer scripts run in Node.js context without direct access to browser (window, document, Web API) context. You need to use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to run code in the browser context and get the data from the document:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const countries = ['us', 'gb', 'ca', 'au', 'de', 'nz', 'albania', 'nl', 'is'];

  const pia = 'https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/network/';
  await page.goto(pia);


  for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    const el = await page.evaluate(country => Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll(`#${country} > div > div > div.modal-body > div > .subregion > center > .hostname`),
      element => element.innerText,
    ), countries[i]);

    for (let j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
      const url = `htpp://${el[j]}:8888/speedtest`;
      console.log(url);
    }
  }
  await browser.close();
})();
```